# Kentico 9 Admin URL changes and locking it to http://localhost

Tags: kentico

I'm reading through the documentation, and don't see what i'm looking for.

This new build is going to run on a staging --> prod set up. On the prod side, I'm hoping to the have the admin login only available to local host. This way you have to be logged into the server to access the admin panel.

I'm assuming i need to make the web.config adjustments, but how do i ensure that only http://localhost/ works?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) on the web server and adding the following rewrite rule to your web.config `system.webServer` section. This should cause IIS to intercept any URLs under /admin and return a 403 if not on a URL local to the server. You might also need to adapt the URL match or add additional rules for other Kentico admin paths (e.g. CMSAdministraton.aspx etc.).

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>
    <rule name="Block Remote Access to Admin" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" enabled="true">
      <match url="admin(/|$)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="localhost" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="::1" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusDescription="Forbidden" statusReason="Access to this URL is restricted"/>
    </rule>
  <rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add custom code in Admin/CMSAdministration.aspx.cs to grant localhost only.